# Disable lateinit null check

Tags: kotlin

Let's say we have the following piece of code, where `loadingPanel` - a `lateinit` field - is used.

```
OverlayPanel().also {
  it.add(loadingPanel)
  it.add(buildMainPanel())
  loadingPanel.clear()
}
```

The above code is compiled to the following

```
OverlayPanel var8 = new OverlayPanel();
$i$f$toTypedArray = false;
boolean var3 = false;
int var5 = false;
LoadingPanel var6 = this.loadingPanel;
if (var6 == null) {
   Intrinsics.throwUninitializedPropertyAccessException("loadingPanel");
   throw null;
} else {
   var8.add((Component)var6);
   var8.add((Component)this.buildMainPanel());
   var6 = this.loadingPanel;
   if (var6 == null) {
      Intrinsics.throwUninitializedPropertyAccessException("loadingPanel");
      throw null;
   } else {
      var6.clear();
      return (JComponent)var8;
   }
}
```

You can clearly see the `null` check is performed twice

```
if (var6 == null) { 
  ...
```

even though we can be sure the field is not `null` after the first one.

Given that, is there a way to tell the compiler to avoid generating those null checks?
It could be useful for release builds where a thrown `RuntimeException` adds little value.

Comment: What is the goal of eliminating the second check?  To save on code size?  To improve performance?  (Generally, this is a problem probably better served by an optimizing postprocessor than by the compiler.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman yes. When the lateinit variable is accessed many times, the checks really become too many imho. This makes the .class file bigger. I'm not really worried about performance, but it can be a point too. Imho, the compiler should offer a flag like the one for parameters. I'd add that I'd like to avoid post processing files, it adds another step to keep track of.

Comment: You're not likely to find an alternative.  The compiler isn't supposed to be particularly smart; it doesn't have to be.

Comment: @LouisWasserman sure, I understand, but then why including the various -Xno-call/param/receiver-assertions flags? We're still talking about null assertions.

Comment: There's a difference between skipping checks entirely -- a semantic change -- and optimizing away checks that are redundant.  If you care about size of class files, build a post-processing step into the entire build so you don't have to keep track of it and it'll address these problems once and for all.

Comment: @LouisWasserman thanks. Btw, would a compiler plugin help in this case?

Comment: It's conceivable that one could, but...you'd be writing a postprocessor, probably from scratch.

Comment: You may want to take a look at Kotlin contracts ( https://github.com/Kotlin/KEEP/blob/master/proposals/kotlin-contracts.md ), they definitely allow you to communicate intent to the compiler. Not sure if the  compiled code will look how you want it to though.